# How to hide sub-total and total rows in the pivot table of Atoti visualization?

Tags: atoti

I would like to hide the sub-total and total row from pivot table. Is that possible? How?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work on atoti*.

There is no feature in the UI to hide the grand total and the sub totals yet. In the meantime, you can change the MDX query stored in the state of your widget.

Here for instance, your MDX should contain something like:

```
Crossjoin(Hierarchize(Descendants({[SomeDimensionName].[CUSTOMERS].[AllMember]}, 1, SELF_AND_BEFORE)), Hierarchize(Descendants({[SomeDimensionName].[S_MAX_DEGRAD].[AllMember]}, 1, SELF_AND_BEFORE)))
```

adapt it like that:

```
Crossjoin([SomeDimensionName].[CUSTOMERS].[CUSTOMERS].Members, [SomeDimensionName].[S_MAX_DEGRAD].[S_MAX_DEGRAD].Members)
```

and the totals will be gone.